# dictionary like data structure with ordered keys and selection between interval of key values

Tags: python, dictionary, intervals

Say I want to store ordered values where the key values represent a lower bound. Like this example:

`d = {1: "pear", 4: "banana", 7: "orange"}`

I can access the first object by `d[1]`. Say I want to store it so that I can access the first object `"pear"` by calling for any value between `[1,4)`. If I input any `"keyvalue"` between `[4,7)` I want `"banana"` to be returned. Is there any type of data structure like that in python? I found `intervalTrees`, but it looked a bit more advanced than what I was looking for. In `intervalTrees` the intervals which are the keys, can be overlapping and I don't want that. Or maybe it is not a dictionary of any type I want since you can mix datatypes as keys in one dictionary. What do you think?

EDIT: From the tip I got, this would be a working code:

```
import bisect

d = [(1, "pear"), (4, "banana"), (7,"orange") ]
keys = [j[0] for j in d]

for v in range(1,10):
    print("Using input ", v)
    i = bisect.bisect(keys, v) - 1
    out = d[i]
    print(out)
    print("")

# Or using SortedDict
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

d2 = SortedDict()
d2[1] = 'pear'
d2[4] = 'banana'
d2[7] = 'orange'

for v in range(1,10):
    print("Using input ", v)
    i = bisect.bisect(d2.keys(), v) - 1
    j = d2.keys()[i]
    out = d2[j]
    print(out)
    print("")
```

Comment: Can you not use a function that returns the dict value of the dict in case the key exists or else banana? Something like `if key in d.keys() return d[key] else return "banana"`

Comment: @xtlc this was not what I meant. I mean that accessing the dict/other data structure should yield this: 1 -> "pear", 2 -> "pear", 3 -> "pear", 4 -> "banana", 5 -> "banana", 6 -> "banana", 7 -> "orange", 8 -> "orange" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure you're looking for is a binary search tree (BST), and preferably a [balanced BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree). Your dictionary keys are the keys of the BST, and each node would just have an additional field to store the corresponding value. Then your lookup is just a lower-bound / bisect-left on the keys. Looking up Python implementations for Red-Black trees or AVL trees returns many possible packages.

There is no builtin library for always-sorted data. If you never need to add or delete keys, you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) with (key, value) tuples in a sorted list.

For a pure Python implementation that allows modification, I would recommend checking out SortedDict from [the SortedContainers library](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html). It's built to be a drop-in replacement for BST's, is very usable and tested, and [claims to outperform](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) pointer-based BST's in memory and speed on reasonably sized datasets (but does not have the same asymptotic guarantees as a BST). You can also provide a custom key for comparing objects of different types.